# MSPDI generate project file

Tags: ms-project, mpxj

My asp.net-application parse mpp-file and save data in db. Then I want to generate xml project-file with the same data using mspdi. All work good besides main first task.
In process of parsing I get one task which is hidden in ms project and this task is parent of all others tasks. 
What is it? 
How can I add this "main hidden task" programmatically? Usual addition make it wrong.

UPD: I use mpxj.

Comment: Here (http://mpxj.sourceforge.net/faq.html) is written "You can ignore the first task if it has an outline level of zero". Ok. But setDuration method doesn't work for task, there are 0 in duration field for all tasks.

Answer (score 0):

That task #0 could be accessed through Project.ProjectSummaryTask. The task isn't available through Project.Tasks

Comment: Zero task is available through project.getAlltasks(). ProjectSummaryTask? I can't find out such property in net.sf.mpxj.Project instance. I use mpxj http://mpxj.sourceforge.net/index.html.

Comment: I could be wrong, but seems they read all of the information or the most of the information into ProjectHeader here: [link to sources](http://mpxj.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/mpxj/src/net/sf/mpxj/mspdi/MSPDIReader.java?view=markup) search for *private void readProjectHeader(Project project)*